# Automatically generating source and doc jars in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, build, jar

Is there a way to automatically generate source and javadoc jars in Netbeans? Ideally I would like to place jars of my source and JavaDoc in the dist folder each time i build.

Comment: What type of project are you creating, Java, Maven, Java Free-Form?  The answer would change depending upon the project type.

Comment: It is a netbeans project, I think it uses ant? Ant is on my list to figure out, but the list is long...:) Not Maven, not familiar with that. I guess freeform. Sorry, no formal code education. I have picked up what little i know from books and helpful people. BTW, Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is what I personally add to my ant files (build.xml) :

```
<target description="bundle sources in a jar" name="package-sources">
  <jar basedir="src" destfile="dist/${ant.project.name}-sources.jar"/>
</target>
<target depends="-javadoc-build" description="bundle javadoc in a jar" name="package-doc">
  <jar basedir="dist/javadoc" destfile="dist/${ant.project.name}-javadoc.jar"/>
</target>
```

With Netbeans call these targets manually, or you can use hook targets :

```
<target name="-post-jar" depends="package-sources, package-doc" />
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Do I just add the lines in build.xml. Because it didn't work for me. What does "With Netbeans call these targets manually, or you can use hook targets" mean?

Comment: Yes, these targets can be added inside the `<project>` element in `build.xml`.

Answer (score 12):

Please try adding this to  build.xml. I've tested it on NetBeans IDE 7.0

```
<target name="-post-jar" description="bundle sources and javadoc in a jar" depends="javadoc">
    <jar compress="${jar.compress}" basedir="${src.dir}" jarfile="${dist.dir}/${application.title}-sources.jar"/>
    <jar compress="${jar.compress}" basedir="${test.src.dir}" jarfile="${dist.dir}/${application.title}-test.jar"/>
    <jar compress="${jar.compress}" basedir="${dist.javadoc.dir}" jarfile="${dist.dir}/${application.title}-javadoc.jar"/>
</target>
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried the following on NetBeans IDE 7.2 and it works (assuming that the project name is  *MyProject*)

1. go to the *MyProject* directory
2. open **build.xml** file in a text editor
3. add the following lines under the line `<import file="nbproject/build-impl.xml"/>`:

   `<target name="-post-jar" description="bundle sources and javadoc in a jar" depends="javadoc">
       <jar compress="${jar.compress}" basedir="${src.dir}" jarfile="${dist.dir}/${application.title}-sources.jar"/>
       <jar compress="${jar.compress}" basedir="${dist.javadoc.dir}" jarfile="${dist.dir}/${application.title}-javadoc.jar"/>
   </target>`
4. go to **nbproject** folder and open the **project.properties** file in a text editor
5. edit the name of the output binary file (set to the project name.jar by default):
   `# This directory is removed when the project is cleaned:
    dist.dir=dist
    dist.jar=${dist.dir}/**MyProject-binaries**.jar`
6. save and build project.

Hope it works with you too.