# How should one distribute the Javadoc for a Library?

Tags: java, jar, javadoc

I am writing a custom library. It's build into a .jar archive. I am fully able to generate the javadoc, but I don't know how I should distribute it?

1. Put it in the same .jar with the library
2. Put it in a different .jar
3. Some other way?

And how to include the javadoc in another project that uses my lib?

1. If I had put it in the same .jar, should I have written something in the manifest?
2. If it's in a separate .jar, is including it in the project enough?

I am using NetBeans 9.1.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'd include the library .jar and the documentation and other things, like a README, License file etc. in a single archive (zip or tar.gz)

mylib-1.0.1.tar.gz , which contains:

```
mylib-1.0.1/
           ├── javadoc
           │   └── index.html  (and all other javadoc files under here)
           ├── mylib-1.0.1.jar
           └── README
```

Instead of the expanded javadoc/ sub directory within the archive, you could add the compressed javadoc in a mylib-1.0.1-javadoc.jar (or zip) , both options are common.

```
mylib-1.0.1/
           ├── mylib-1.0.1-javadoc.jar
           ├── mylib-1.0.1.jar
           └── README
```

Comment: the javadoc consists of many files, so I'd prefer it compressed and archived. On the other hand, it's my fault that I though that it may be something special as I thought that the "add jar/zip" command in netbeans was only for libraries, but it's for virtually any resource. Thanks!

Comment: If you do it like this, Eclipse is able to link to the Javadoc from references. Good method indeed. Also is what Maven repositories tend to do: http://search.maven.org/#browse|1803601404

Answer (score 3):

It's a general practice to keep the JavaDocs in a separate archive. or even more commonly, in a directory called 'docs'. you do not needlessly want to bloat your library's archive with the html and js files.

And why would you want to include the generated JavaDocs [html + js] in your project? As long the source code JavaDoc comments are in place, someone using your library will be able to see them by simply hovering over w/ the mouse in any of the modern IDE's

**Update**
As per nanda's comment below, I checked the same and he IS correct. In my project, I have actually attached Javadocs from the 'doc' folder to the archive to be able to view them on mouseover.

Comment: not true... if you compile the java classes normally you will lose all comments. Even IDE can't recover it. You should include the source in another jar IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:
For me this was the best choise: (addingto build.xml. I've tested it on NetBeans IDE 7.0 and 7.2.1) (found it on [Automatically generating source and doc jars in Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855498/automatically-generating-source-and-doc-jars-in-netbeans) )

```
<target name="-post-jar" description="bundle sources and javadoc in a jar" depends="javadoc">
<jar compress="${jar.compress}" basedir="${src.dir}" jarfile="${dist.dir}/${application.title}-sources.jar"/>
<jar compress="${jar.compress}" basedir="${test.src.dir}" jarfile="${dist.dir}/${application.title}-test.jar"/>
<jar compress="${jar.compress}" basedir="${dist.javadoc.dir}" jarfile="${dist.dir}/${application.title}-javadoc.jar"/>
```

This will create four jars, one to application program, one to sources, one to tests and one to javadoc.