# Export project to jar file including javadoc

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, documentation, javadoc

I was wondering if there's a way to export a project to a .jar file that INCLUDES its javadoc instead of creating a properties file in each project that includes that jar, as suggested in the question below.

[How to attach javadoc or sources to jars in libs folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873152/how-to-attach-javadoc-or-sources-to-jars-in-libs-folder/11579339#11579339)

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, not possible. You must create your javadoc as a separated file and somehow distribute it together with your JAR.

Look at these questions:
[How should one distribute the Javadoc for a Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880757/how-should-one-distribute-the-javadoc-for-a-library)

[How do I create a jar distributable for javadocs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126712/how-do-i-create-a-jar-distributable-for-javadocs)