# Dependent Jar download with sources and javadocs in gradle

Tags: eclipse, maven, gradle, jar

> Maven Micro-Tip: Get sources and Javadocs
>
> When you're using Maven in an IDE you often find the need for your IDE
>   to resolve source code and Javadocs for your library dependencies.
>   There's an easy way to accomplish that goal.
>
> ```
> mvn dependency:sources
> mvn dependency:resolve -Dclassifier=javadoc
> ```
>
> The first command will attempt to download source code for each of the
>   dependencies in your pom file.
>
> The second command will attempt to download the Javadocs.
>
> Maven is at the mercy of the library packagers here. So some of them
>   won't have source code packaged and many of them won't have Javadocs.

I want to get all javadoc and sources in Gradle. For this I have got the command

```
   downloadSources=true
   downloadJavadoc=true
```

But it is not downloading sources of all dependendent jars. Could you please help me : What will be the gradle command?

I have got some links which are related to Maven. But I don't get anything in Gradle.

### Related links for Maven:

1. [Source and Javadoc jar generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023373/source-and-javadoc-jar-generation)
2. [Maven – Always download sources and javadocs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780758/maven-always-download-sources-and-javadocs)

I have also follow this [link for gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28404149/how-to-download-javadocs-and-sources-for-jar-using-gradle-2-0). But it is not downloading dependent sources and javadocs. So please suggest me.

Anykind of help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? if yes try this     System.setProperty('http.proxyHost','yourproxyurl')       
    System.setProperty('http.proxyPort', '80')

Comment: @Sumang There is no proxy

Comment: As already stated in the docs you mentioned. Some artifacts don't have source or javadoc or nothing....What is your problem?

Comment: @khmarbaise I want to get dependent jar files with their source file. But getting only jars. No javadocs or sources. Would you please tell me how can i get javadocs or sources of dependent jars. Thanks

Comment: Some artifacts in central don't have javadoc nor source code. So you can't change that.

Comment: But is it possible to get which have javadoc and source code? @khmarbaise