# Netbeans java jar with javadocs and sources using xml and properties file

Tags: java, xml, properties, javadoc

I'm using netbeans 8.1. How can I add a **Javadocs** to a Project_Name.jar file without using the **Edit Jar Reference?**

I tried to use the build.xml file in my java project but I can only create a **javadocs.jar**  and **javadocs folder** .

This is the code I tried thanks to **user805575** [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6404018/15621986)

```
<target name="-post-jar" description="bundle sources and javadoc in a jar" depends="javadoc">
<jar compress="${jar.compress}" basedir="${src.dir}" jarfile="${dist.dir}/${application.title}-sources.jar"/>
<jar compress="${jar.compress}" basedir="${test.src.dir}" jarfile="${dist.dir}/${application.title}-test.jar"/>
<jar compress="${jar.compress}" basedir="${dist.javadoc.dir}" jarfile="${dist.dir}/${application.title}-javadoc.jar"/>
```

This code allow me to create a javadoc.jar and source.jar, but what I want is to already add the **javadocs** and **sources** to the Project_Name.jar to avoid manually adding it when I **clean and build**

> In the folder of **nbproject** there is a file name **project.properties**, i see a code `excludes=file.reference.Project_Name-javadoc.jar = dist\\Project_Name-javadoc.jar` which i manually add the javadocs using the **Edit Jar Reference** how can I code this in .xml file or .properties? So I can use my jar in any java project with **Javadocs**

Comment: You should use Maven or Gradle as a dependency management system.  Netbeans has built in support for both Maven and Gradle

Comment: Can you help me with the code? Im new to maven and gradle 

Answer (score 0):

To create a new maven project in Netbeans go File->New Project
You should see a this
[image: New Maven Project]

This will create a new Maven project
You can then use Maven to build your project. This will create your sources jar as well, which I assume you are refering to when you say javadocs.

If you plan to become a Java developer tools such as Maven are vital. It will be well worth your time reading up here
https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html